# I opened VScode from Anaconda and running it in conda based python environment, but numpy is not activated

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, visual-studio-code

I installed Anaconda and VScode, and running in Python 2.7.15 conda based environment, but numpy can not be used. I checked Anaconda Navigator and all numpy plugins are installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a conda environment that specifies numpy as a dependency instead of running directly out of the 'base' environment.

Comment: I tried to delete everything and install anaconda. It works now, but thank you very much for your kindness